# Can't get inline blocks to align

Tags: css, jsfiddle

Can any one explain why the ".name-wrap" div is not aligning with the image in this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gwnN8/).

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<style>

.element-wrap{
    display:block;
    background:blue
}

.name-wrap{
    display:inline-block;
    background:yellow
}

.model-name-wrap{
    display:block
}

.make-name-wrap{
    display:block
}

img{
 display:inline-block   
}

</style>

<body>  
<div  class="element-wrap">
<img  height="50" width="50" src="https://fbcdn-photos-h-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-prn1/c8.0.50.50/p50x50/1012747_10100658463725213_1269934886_s.jpg">
<div  class="name-wrap">
<div class="model-name-wrap">Honda</div>
<div  class="make-name-wrap">Civic</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `vertical-align: middle;` for `img` tag as well as `.name-wrap`

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/mzpCf/)

Relevant CSS which has to be modified :

```
.name-wrap{
    display:inline-block;
    background:yellow;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

img{
   display:inline-block;
   vertical-align: middle;        
}
```

Answer (score 0):

css change

http://jsfiddle.net/gwnN8/5/

```
.element-wrap{
    display:block;
    background:blue;
        float:left;
    width:100%;
}
.element-wrap img{
float:left;
}

.name-wrap{
    display:inline-block;
    float:left;
    background:yellow
}

.model-name-wrap{
    display:block
}

.make-name-wrap{
    display:block
}
```